# How to return the index value of transaction?

Tags: solidity

I wish to return the new index value once the transaction is done.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
contract Courses {

    struct Instructor {
        uint age;
        string fName;
        string lName;
    }

    mapping (address => Instructor) instructors;
    address[] public instructorAccts;

    function setInstructor(address _address, uint _age, string _fName, string _lName) public {
        var instructor = instructors[_address];

        instructor.age = _age;
        instructor.fName = _fName;
        instructor.lName = _lName;

        instructorAccts.push(_address) -1;
    }

    function getInstructors() view public returns(address[]) {
        return instructorAccts;
    }

    function getInstructor(address _address) view public returns (uint, string, string) {
        return (instructors[_address].age, instructors[_address].fName, instructors[_address].lName);
    }

    function countInstructors() view public returns (uint) {
        return instructorAccts.length;
    }
}
```

So in the setInstructor I wish to return the index value like 0,1,2 (Whatever the index value will be there of public key index).

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

```
function setInstructor(address _address, uint _age, string _fName, string _lName) public returns(uint256){
    var instructor = instructors[_address];

    instructor.age = _age;
    instructor.fName = _fName;
    instructor.lName = _lName;

    return instructorAccts.push(_address) -1;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this do not work when we compile on injected web on remix . It will only work on VM. How can I make it work on injected web 3 or on live environment.

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work, what error you got?

Comment: It should work Shrey

Comment: Let me try again.

Answer (score 1):

`geth` is returning transaction hash and `remix` is returning index. This is a fundamental difference in behavior of `geth` and `remix`. The return value of a `setInstructor.sendTransaction` method is always the hash of the transaction that’s created. Transactions don’t return a contract value to the front end because transactions are not immediately mined and included in the blockchain.
To get values from a function you should use solidity events.

Refer to [this](https://media.consensys.net/technical-introduction-to-events-and-logs-in-ethereum-a074d65dd61e)  blog for understanding more about solidity events.

Refer [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/51039/why-to-write-return-statements-in-solidity-function) question to understand why to write return statements in solidity functions.