# How can Remix Ethereum decode output address of smart contract is created from another smart contract

Tags: web3js, remix

I have seen that when I create a new smart contract from another smart contract Remix Ethereum return to me the address of smart contract.
But When I do it with web3js the callback function just return to me a transactionHash and no more information. 
When I try to get eth.getTransactionReceipt("transactionHash") I saw contractAddress is null.

I can work arround by use event but my question is that How can Remix Ethereum can do that?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Project {
    address public founder;
    constructor () public {
        founder = msg.sender;
    }
    function createRequest(string _title) public returns (address) {
        address addrRequest = new Request(_title);
        return addrRequest;
    }
}

contract Request {
    string public title;
    constructor(string _title) public {
        title = _title;
    }
}
```

Result from remix ethereum tool
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of a `sendTransaction` method is always the hash of the transaction that’s created. Transactions don’t return a contract value to the front end because transactions are not immediately mined and included in the blockchain.
To get values from a function you should use solidity events.

Refer to [this](https://media.consensys.net/technical-introduction-to-events-and-logs-in-ethereum-a074d65dd61e)  blog for understanding more about solidity events.

Refer [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/51039/why-to-write-return-statements-in-solidity-function) question to understand why to write return statements in solidity function.

Comment: so that in remix tool it also use somehow a event to capture that information. Is it correct?

Comment: No, currently you are using javascript vm of Remix with the help of which transaction is executed immediately. If you try to execute the same function on injected web3 you will get transaction hash.

Comment: Please refer the following documentation for more details https://remix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/run_tab.html